# Samsug Galaxy J7 First charge?

Tags: samsung, charging

Alright so i got a brand new J7 and the first day was going fine, i waited for the battery to go to 5% and i'm charging it now. Am i supposed to let it charge to 100%? Or i can **INTRERUPT** (good grammar.) it at like 70% like that. I need answers fast please! Thank you!

**YS JP**

Comment: No. Not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charging the device to 80-90% is good and always put in one long charge cycle like from 5-10% to 80-90% rather then multiple small charge cycles